# print the summation of an array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create an array of 1 to 100 and print the summation of the elements.

Actually, I have used for loop and Array together! But it won't work.

```
  int i, sum = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
      int [] arr = new int [] {i};
            sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
            System.out.println("Sum of all the elements of an array: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: You create a new array in each loop iteration with one element. That is not what you want.  And the access of `arr[i]` will throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException right away.

Comment: Do you know how you can create an (empty) array with 100 elements?

Comment: @xFive the solution you selected as the answer is innacurate. Try running these two arrays `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `{10,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}`. Both will add up to 55.

Comment: @xFive I also noticed the line `arr[i] = i+1;` This OVERRIDES the values of the array with the value of the counter. Totally incorrect. You are not supposed to mutate the array. You are supposed to _read_ the values and add them up.

Comment: @xFive this is why you need to test out code with different inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "one-liner" solution.

```
int[] arr = {...}; // Your array here
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + arr[i]; // can also be written as sum += arr[i];
}

System.out.println("Sum of all the elements of an array: " + sum);
```

If the array is empty, the sum will be zero. Otherwise, it is the accumulated sum. The best thing to do is to declare and increment the loop counter variable inside the `for` structure and not outside. That's how it is designed. If you need this variable accessible outside the loop, use a `while` loop instead.

UPDATE: In case you're curious for a `while` loop equivalent:

```
int[] arr = {...}; // Your array here
int sum = 0;
int i = 0; 
while (i < arr.length) {
    sum = sum + arr[i]; // can also be written as sum += arr[i];
    i++; // always increment the variable at the end of the loop
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
int i, sum = 0;
        int[] arr = new int[100];
        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = i+1;
            sum += arr[i];
        }
         System.out.println("Sum of all the elements of an array: " + sum);
```

Comment: Ya! Uh I just was missing the arr[i] = i +1 Hmm! Thank you so much bruh!

Comment: @xFive no, you also declared the array very differently

Comment: No problem, do not forget to mark the answer as accepted if it is your solution, thx

Comment: @Devck-DC this is not an accurate solution. It skips the value of index 0. Change the value of that index to anything other than 1, and it will give you a bad result.

Comment: @Devck-DC if you run the following `{10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10}` thru your code, will it it output 100 (correct) or 55 (incorrect)?

Comment: As you can see, @xFive is requesting the array from 1 to 100, that is why I have skipped 0

Comment: and in case you are talking about the index inside the loop, it is not skipping it either, the ```ì+1``` is being used as a temporary value which is not affecting the index of the loop

Comment: @Devck-DC your solution ALWAYS outputs the same sum, which renders this solution useless. The `1 to 100` wasn't necessarily regarding the values. It is regarding the size of the array. This is how it is worded in many code sites like Hackerrank and Leetcode. The exercise is to add up the values of the array to produce a sum. Your solution overwrites the values in the array with their index location. In no real-word scenario, this is an acceptable solution.